# Save attachments in order

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

I am trying to run a macro via rule in Outlook that saves attachments into a folder.

Emails sometimes have more than one attachment. I am trying to save the files in order, so for example if I go to down the emails I can easily see the file that corresponds to it.

I have the following that I found online:

```
Public Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
    Dim saveFolder As String
    saveFolder = "C:\PathToDirectory\"

    Dim dateFormat As String
    dateFormat = Format(itm.ReceivedTime, "yyyy-mm-dd Hmm ")

    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
    Next

End Sub
```

I've tried to play with `objatt.displayname` with no luck. I've tried assigning new names and creating a new loop that names the files File 1 , File 2 and so on but when I do that I lose the file extension.

Updated Version:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub save_attachments(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strExt As String
Dim i As Long
Dim savefolder As String

i = 1

savefolder = "C:\Users\w\desktop\test"

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    i = i + 1
    strExt = fso.GetExtensionName(objAtt.DisplayName)
    objAtt.SaveAsFile savefolder & "\" & dateFormat & " - File " & i & "." & strExt
Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this in your existing subroutine. This would increment a `"File"` number and still preserve the extension.

```
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strExt As String
Dim i As Long

For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
    i = i + 1
    strExt = fso.GetExtensionName(objAtt.DisplayName)
    objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & " - File " & i & "." & strExt
Next
```

Comment: I tried this and it only saves one of the documents. It doesn't loop through all of them. I added save folder path.

Comment: Hmm. The `For Each` should iterate each attachment. Are you sure the `MailItem` you processed had multiple attachments?

Comment: Not all of them have multiple attachments. Some of them are single. I do want to name them file1 2 3 regardless of how many attachments in the email.

Comment: This should do that. The loop is the same as before. If it worked before, it should work now. Maybe you can edit your question and append your latest code.

Comment: I just updated my original post. It is really weird because if the person that sent the email has a picture in the signature, it is also exporting that.

Comment: You need to declare objAtt and add the dateFormat lines, like you had before.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using a similar solution for some time now. I recently added this peace of coding to avoid saving embedded images too:

```
Extension = LCase$(Right$(FileNm, 3))
If Extension = "png" Or Extension = "gif" Or Extension = "jpg" Then 

*** Save File ***

Endif
```

Assuming of course you don't receive image files you want to save.

If you put this before your For Next loop, you can select multiple e-mails:

```
For Each Item In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
```

Of course you will have to put your i = i + 1 somewhere else too then.

You can also put a link to your file in the e-mail:

```
FileNameb = Replace(filename, " ", "%20")
Link = "<a href=" + FileNameb + ">" + filename + "</a><br />"
Item.HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody + Link
```

And this removes the attachments from the mail and saves it:

```
For i = 1 To Item.Attachments.Count
    Item.Attachments.Remove 1: 'Remove all attachments
Next i
Item.UnRead = False: 'Mark e mail as read
Item.Save
```

Have fun!